# How to send and receive certificates in Spring Ws with a third party such as Bank?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, ssl, spring-ws

I am using Spring MVC 4 Rest but now as i need to consume a web service i decided to use Spring Ws with Appache Tomcat7 server and I am trying to connect to a third party that is a Bank Api I have to achieve mutual authentication that is two way SSL in order to send my Soap Requests

1. If certificates are placed in the trust store and key store
   respectively in spring ws then while trying to connect to https
   server will the verification and sending certificates happen
   automatically?
2. What are the steps or procedures to be followed to configure my Spring Ws       application to consume a web service over https ?
3. If verification and sending is not done automatically  then how do i send and verify the
       certificate before sending the soap request using Spring ws?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?
I'm currently following this tutorial: https://www.codenotfound.com/2017/07/spring-ws-mutual-authentication-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring WS security provides support via [WebServiceTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html). There are two kinds of security mechanism, SUN's XML and Web Services Security(XWSS) through XwsSecurityInterceptor and Apache's WSS4J throughWss4jSecurityInterceptor. These are just extension points, so you can customize all your security needs ranging from authentication, signing, validation, encryption and decryption.

Please also check my answer regarding keystores and truststore set up to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608813/how-does-java-handle-certificates-in-spring-ws) question.

More reading here [XwsSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#security-xws-security-interceptor) and [Wss4jSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#security-wss4j-security-interceptor).

Comment: In Two way SSL configuration is the certificate exchange and verification done by tomcat itself or I need to use a security interceptor for achieving two way ssl commnication

Comment: You can use tomcat for certificate exchange and verification but for authentication, signing, validation and encryption/decryption you'll need the ws security implementation which spring ws provides with the interceptors.