# How does Java handle Certificates in Spring Ws?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, keystore, truststore

I need to consume a web Service using Spring Ws . I am using WEB service Template.
I need to know that  by only specifying the certificates in java keystore and trustore will the sending and receiving of certificates happen automatically? Also will the verification of server certificates happen automatically in Spring Ws if the keystore and trustore is configured properly or do I have to write some code?if not Ho do I send and receive certificates in Spring WS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have [selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520365/how-to-send-and-receive-certificates-in-spring-ws-with-a-third-party-such-as-ban) the security interceptor you like to use. Assuming you have all the certificates handy, you can follow below links to set up the one or two way ssl for each of the security interceptor. This links are not most up to date but should get you started.

**XwsSecurityInterceptor**

[Server Security Set up](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2009/01/)

[Client Security Set up](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2009/03/)

**Wss4jSecurityInteceptor**

[Client and Server Security Set up](http://blog.krecan.net/2010/06/07/spring-ws-security-on-both-client-and-server/)

Comment: In Two way SSL configuration is the certificate exchange and verification done by tomcat itself or I need to use a security interceptor for achieving two way ssl commnication